# How do I make it so when a user deletes something it still exists, but is just hidden from everyone?

Tags: cakephp

Currently when a user deletes an item, it gets properly deleted, but due to the structure of my database and wanting to preserve data I would rather simply hide it from everyone except the admin but have it appear deleted to the user.

Here is an example of how I am currently deleting items from the View:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->postLink(__('Delete'), array('action' => 'delete', $serial['Serial']['id']), null, __('Are you sure you want to delete # %s?', $serial['Serial']['id'])); ?>
```

And here is the delete function that is called in the Controller:

```
    public function delete($id = null) {
        $this->Serial->id = $id;
        if (!$this->Serial->exists()) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid serial'));
        }
        $this->request->onlyAllow('post', 'delete');
        if ($this->Serial->delete()) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The serial has been deleted.'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The serial could not be deleted. Please, try again.'));
        }
        return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> How do I make it so when a user deletes something it still exists, but is just hidden from everyone?

By not deleting, but just flagging it as deleted (using an extra `deleted` column or similar) and excluding such flagged records from your find operations (using for example the `Model::beforeFind()` callback to inject a condition like `deleted = 0`).

Just search for "*soft delete*", and you'll find ready made behaviors such as

- [**CakeDC Utils - SoftDelete**](https://github.com/CakeDC/utils#softdelete-behavior)
- [**dereuromark CakePHP Tools - SoftDelete**](https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-tools/blob/master/Model/Behavior/SoftDeleteBehavior.php)

Answer (score 0):

Use  database flag like `deleted` as enum which can be 1 Or 0 , So If you click on delete , it updates as 1 , Like soft delete.

So in model , use condition to fetch only recs with deleted status as 0 .

Or in controller use find query with condition to fetch only recs with deleted status as 0 .